# VB : If variable is anything else?

Tags: vb.net

I'm just learning Visual Basic. I tried to make a calculator but I want it so if you anything else that isn't in the if statement thing it says "Sorry" and returns to the beginning. Here's the code:

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    Dim op As String
    Console.WriteLine("Calculator")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Valid Operators :")
    Console.WriteLine("+(Addition), -(Subtraction), *(Multiplication) & /(Division)")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Number 1 :")
    num1 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Number 2 :")
    num2 = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Operator :")
    op = Console.ReadLine()
    If op = "+" Then
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
        Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2)
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
    If op = "-" Then
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
        Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2)
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
    If op = "*" Then
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
        Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2)
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
    If op = "/" Then
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
        Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2)
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
    If op = Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("You have not entered a valid operator.")
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If

  End Sub

End Module
```

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: You're looking for `Else If` or `Switch`.

Comment: You don't need to write code to print `"Press <Enter> To Exit"` 5 times.

Comment: Go to your project properties and change the Option Strict Off to On as soon as possible.

Comment: @Doorknob: Saying that without explaining _why_ is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a switch statement (`Select Case` in VB).  All of the empty `WriteLine` statements aren't necessary either.

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim finished As Boolean = False

    While Not finished

      Dim num1 As Integer
      Dim num2 As Integer
      Dim op As String
      Console.WriteLine("Calculator" & Environment.Newline)
      Console.WriteLine("Valid Operators :")
      Console.WriteLine("+(Addition), -(Subtraction), *(Multiplication) & /(Division)" & Environment.Newline)
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Number 1 :")
      num1 = Console.ReadLine()
      Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "Enter Number 2 :")
      num2 = Console.ReadLine()
      Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "Enter Operator :")
      op = Console.ReadLine()

      Select Case op
        Case "+" 
          Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "Answer :")
          Console.WriteLine((num1 + num2) & Environment.Newline)
          Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
          Console.ReadLine()
          finished = True

        Case "-" 
          Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "Answer :")
          Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2 & Environment.Newline)
          Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
          Console.ReadLine()
          finished = True

        Case"*"
          Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "Answer :")
          Console.WriteLine((num1 * num2) & Environment.Newline)
          Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
          Console.ReadLine()
          finished = True

        Case "/"
          Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "Answer :")
          Console.WriteLine((num1 / num2) & Environment.Newline)
          Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
          Console.ReadLine()
          finished = True

        Case Is Nothing 
          Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "You have not entered a valid operator." & Environment.Newline)
          Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
          Console.ReadLine()

        Case Else
          Console.WriteLine(Environment.Newline & "Sorry." & Environment.Newline)
          Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
          Console.ReadLine() 

      End Select

    End While  

  End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name your lines like this:

```
Line1:
```

and then in your code you can use this:

```
Goto Line1
```

FYI, I will get downvoted if I dont tell you, this should not be done because it is bad practice!

Comment: It probably isn't very useful to give him an answer that "should not be done".

Comment: There is always an exception to the rule.

Comment: perhaps, but I would say that this example definitely is NOT a good candidate for making an exception and using `GoTo`.

Comment: True, but it isn't a real world application anyway. It is a learning project and "we learn by our mistakes".  In this case, user2832616 will learn that he/she should not do this. But if we just say dont do this, they will go somewhere else to get thier answer.

Comment: At least you gave a disclaimer, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this with Select-case statement within a Do-Loop loop, so in your code, right before you do:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Number 1 :")
```

I would add a

```
Do
```

And right at the end, before the last if statement, I would add the

```
Loop
```

So that will create the "returns to the beginning" effect

Inside the last if statement I would do

```
Exit Do
```

If the exit condition would have met. (Execution will go to the first line after the Loop command).

```
.
.
.
Do
  Select Case op
  Case "+" 
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2)
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
    Console.ReadLine()

  Case "-" 
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2)
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
    Console.ReadLine()

  Case"*"
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
    Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2)
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
    Console.ReadLine()

  Case "/"
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Answer :")
    Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2)
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
    Console.ReadLine()

  Case Is Nothing 
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("You have not entered a valid operator.")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
    exit = Console.ReadLine()

    //test here for exit and if exit do:

    Exit Do

  Case Else
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry")
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> To Exit")
    Console.ReadLine() 

End Select

Loop
```